# Erro do tkinter na reentrada

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estava usando `tkinter`, fiz o codigo normalmente, e quando executei o mesmo, estava tudo funcionando normalmente, mas, quando saí do programa e entrei novamente ele deu erro:

> meu codigo:

```py
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

def meu_jogo():
    computador = randint(1, 10)
    texto_ganhador['text'] = 'O computador pensou no número {}'.format(computador)

janela = Tk()
janela.title('meu primeiro teste')

label = Label(janela, text='O computador irá sortea um número para você entre 0 a 10')
label.grid(column=0,row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

button = Button(janela, text='clique aqui para começar', command=meu_jogo)
button.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=10)

texto_ganhador = Label(janela, text='')
texto_ganhador.grid(column=0,row=2)

janela.mainloop()
```

> erro:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/PySimpleGUI/tkinter.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/PySimpleGUI/tkinter.py", line 8, in <module>
    janela = Tk()
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined
```

não entendo porque está acontecendo isso, Na primeira vez rodou como o esperado. Queria resolver esse erro, mas, não sei como.

Comment: Alguma solução do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275818/programming-in-python-getting-name-tk-is-not-defined-only-at-command-prompt/45117202) ajuda você?

Comment: Sim, o meu problema foi resolvido, muito obrigado!